# Is it possible to have a constructor with void return type?

Tags: java, constructor

I would like to know whether it is possible to have a constructor with void return type as in the below example.

**For example**

```
class A
{
    void A(){}  //where A is constructor and for which return type is void

    public static void main(string arg[]){
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructors do not have a return type.

Comment: @Naresh, if you got your problem solved / understood how it works, please select the answer. It would help others to identify easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constructor does not have a result / return type.

If you add a result / return type to a "constructor" you turn it into a method whose name is the same as the class name.  Then `new` won't be able to use it, and any `this(...)` or `super(...)` call in the method will be a syntax error.

---

For your example, you won't actually get an error.  That is because Java will add a default no-args constructor for `A` ... because you haven't actually defined *any* constructors.  The `new` in your example will actually be using the default constructor ....

If you changed your code to this:

```
class A {
    void A() { System.err.println("hello"); }

    public static void main(string arg[]) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

and compiled and ran it, you should see that it DOES NOT give you any output.  Remove the `void` and you will see output.

---

> so here A() work as a method

It >>is<< a method.  But it is not "working".  As my version of your example shows ... the method is not being called at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused why your code compiles. It's because `A()` is not actually a constructor but a method (that unfortunately has the same name as the class). The class `A` has an implicit default constructor which is used by `main`. The method `A()` is not used.

As others have pointed out, constructors do not have a return type.

Comment: A() is a method. A constructor does not have a return type, so as you wrote void in front of A(), you've defined a method, not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors don't have return type - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example would be more easy to understand. In this example you can see `Main` as the class, constructor and method and how those works. Please see the output too.
See what happens when you call the constructor and what happens when the method called with constructor.

**Program:**

```
//Class
public class Main
{
    //Constructor
    public Main(){ 
        System.out.println("Hello World 1");
    }

   //Method
    public void Main(){ 
        System.out.println("Hello World 2");
    }

   //Another method but static
    public static void main(String[] args) { //This should be small letter 'main'
        System.out.println("Hello World 3"); //Print this first

        Main constructor = new Main(); //Run constructor and print.
        constructor.Main(); //Run method (void Main()) and print.
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World 3                                                                                                                         
Hello World 1                                                                                                                         
Hello World 2
```

**Note:** Naming conventions not followed.